Can you translate these hieroglyphs?
Translate this following paragraph written in a Unicode encoding of Middle Egyptian hieroglyphs circa 1700 BCE to English. The text is written first from left to right and then from top to bottom, like in English.
Hint:

 Remember that the principles of Middle Egyptian spelling are very complex. Uniliteral and multiliteral signs are often used within the same text and several hieroglyphs are used only to indicate the context of the previous hieroglyph; there are also multiple ways to write the same word and inflection within the language. Furthermore, the plural forms of nouns end in -w, but they can be written by writing the singular form of the glyph three times in a row in addition to using a uniliteral sign for w or leaving the plural unmarked. Try creating a romanization of the text first and then breaking that down into smaller words to form the full text in romanized Egyptian; subsequently translate that to English. It would also help you to paste the hieroglyphs into a word processor because they appear very small on your screen.


